# add new domain active directory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am a beginner user to active directory I want ajouter another active directory domain. I have a domain in my active directory . if I type in the menu execute dcpromo Active Directory Installation Wizard Before you install or remove Active Directory, you must remove Certificate Services who can help me please

Comment: I think you're a little out of your depth here. First of all the message you're getting says what it means and means what it says, there's not much to add to it. Secondly, a domain controller can only be a domain controller for *one* domain. There's nothing wrong with being a beginner, but if this is a production network I strongly suggest you get some experienced help or at least some training before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new domain to your existing forest then you need to run dcpromo on another server in the domain. You don't run dcpromo on your existing DC.